# grep command to display all lines that begins and ends with same character

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to know how to use `grep` in order to display all lines that begin and end with the same character.

Answer (score 14):

POSIXly:

```
pattern='\(.\).*\1
.'
grep -x -- "$pattern" file
```

It won't work if line starts or ends with invalid byte character, if you want to cover that case, you can add `LC_ALL=C`, although `LC_ALL=C` works with single-byte character data only.

---

`perl6` seems to be the best tool, if you have it in your box:

```
$ printf '\ue7\u301 blah \u107\u327\n121\n1\n123\n' |
  perl6 -ne '.say if m/^(.).*$0$/ || /^.$/'
ḉ blah ḉ
121
1
```

Although it still chokes on invalid characters.

---

Note that `perl6` will alter your text by turning it to `NFC` form:

```
$ printf '\u0044\u0323\u0307\n' |
  perl6 -pe ''                  |
  perl -CI -ne 'printf "U+%04x\n", ord for split //'
U+1e0c
U+0307
U+000a

$ printf '\u0044\u0323\u0307\n' |
  perl -pe ''                   |
  perl -CI -ne 'printf "U+%04x\n", ord for split //'
U+0044
U+0323
U+0307
U+000a
```

Internally, `perl6` stores string in `NFG` form (stand for `Normalization Form Grapheme`), which is `perl6` invented way to deal with un-precomposed graphemes properly:

```
$ printf '\u0044\u0323\u0307\n' | perl6 -ne '.chars.say'
1
$ printf '\u0044\u0323\u0307\n' | perl6 -ne '.codes.say'
2
```

Comment: Perl's handling of Unicode text is nothing short of exemplary, to the point that many "simple" tasks in Perl are practically impossible to implement using other tools, at least with the same level of correctness.

Comment: It should be noted that `perl6` will alter the text though (turn it to NFC (Normalization form "composed")).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Yes, fair point. Also note that string in `perl6` is store in `NFG` form (`G` for `Grapheme`), which is `perl6` way to deal with un-precomposed graphemes properly.

Answer (score 10):

Not grep but awk:

```
awk -F "" 'NF && $1 == $NF'
```

These special cases are handled:

- it does not print empty lines
- it always prints 1-character lines

An empty FS splits the record into one character per field in `gawk`, `mawk` and `busybox` `awk` (bytes, not characters for the latter two), but is not standard and doesn't work in the implementations of `awk` derived from the original one by A, W and K like on BSDs and commercial Unices. More portable but more to type:

```
awk '/./ && substr($0,1,1) == substr($0,length)'
```

Comment: Note that `FS` as empty string is not standard, and won't work in some `awk` implementation.

Comment: Alternative that avoids splitting and is fully portable (even to the maximally awful Solaris 'old' awk) `awk 'length&&substr($0,1,1)==substr($0,length)'` (note default argument of `length` is `$0`, and default action is `{print $0}`)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: thx, I'm only using your default action hint to have the shortest command.

Comment: Firne. One minor correction; my test for Solaris old awk was mistaken (I accidentally had xpg4 on) but this method does work in `nawk` which is almost as bad :-)

Answer (score 8):

```
grep -xe '\(.\).*\1' -e .
```

Example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' il y était cet été  | grep -xe '\(.\).*\1' -e .
y
été
```

`-x` is for *exact* match (match on the whole line). `\1` being a back-reference to the character captured in `\(.\)`. We add a `-e .` to take care of the special case of a line containing one single character.

It assumes the input contains valid text in the current locale.

The match is on *character*, not *byte* (those é in UTF-8 are the two bytes 0xc3 0xa9 for instance), nor *graphem cluster* (it wouldn't work if those é were written in their decomposed form with `e` followed by the U+0301 combining acute accent for instance).

To work on graphem clusters, with a `grep` that supports `-P` for PCRE:

```
$ printf 'e\u0301te\u0301\n' | grep -xPe '(\X).*\1|\X'
été
```

That assumes the decomposition is the same for the two clusters, for instance a `ḉ` expressed as `c` `U+0301` `U+0327` would not match one expressed as `c` `U+0327` `U+0301` or `ć` (`U+0107`) `U+0327` or `ç` (`U+00E7`) `U+0301` or ḉ (`U+1E09`). For that, you'd need to do the check on a normalized form:

```
$ printf '\ue7\u301 blah \u107\u327\n' |
  perl -MUnicode::Normalize -C -ne '
    print if /^\X$/ || NFC($_) =~ /^(\X).*\1$/'
ḉ blah ḉ
```

Comment: If you have `perl6`, then `perl6 -ne '.say if m/^(.).*$0$/ || /^.$/'` should do all the works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Quick python2 alternative:

```
python -c 'import sys;[sys.stdout.write(l) for l in sys.stdin if len(l)>1 and l.rstrip("\n").endswith(l[0])]' < input.txt
```

Example:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;[sys.stdout.write(l) for l in sys.stdin if len(l)>1 and l.rstrip("\n").endswith(l[0])]' < input.txt  | cat -A 
nathan$
 ookie $
a line a$
```

Comment: It's failed if line contains trailing or leading spaces, example ` 121`.

Comment: @cuonglm that's true. But was trailing or leading whitespace a requirement ? This  does the job asked - check if the leading and last character are the same. Whitespace is still an ascii character, no ?

Comment: @cuonglm yours failed with trailing and leading space too, by the way :)

Comment: Your code removes leading and trailing white spaces, so it changes the input line. Also it gives an error for empty lines.

Comment: @Serg: How? my answer only grepping, it doesn't modify the input.

Comment: @cuonglm http://paste.ubuntu.com/23210975/ See the output. The line with leading whitespace is not printed

Comment: @rudimeier I've addressed the empty  line issue

Comment: @Serg: I think that's the requirement, the first char is space, the last isn't, so the line won't be printed.

Comment: @Serg in your pastebin example, the line with a leading space isn't printed because it doesn't end with a space. Therefore, the 1st character (a space) isn't the same as thew last one.

Comment: @cuonglm OK, I think I misunderstood what you were saying there, because in the first comment you have ' 121' , so I didn't understand you mean the line starting with space and ending with space.

Comment: Your code still fails if input contains only spaces. BTW you are always printing at least one newline, even though the input is empty or does not have any wanted lines.

Comment: Made a small edit, now it works properly, only strips newlines for comparison, and added different test output